# utilizando console

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Iniciando projeto com vagrant, ao utilizar o console, aparece uma mensagem de 'Unable to load pry' veja abaixo completo:

```
$ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 4.1.4)
=> Unable to load pry
irb(main):001:0>
```

após isso tento executar.

```
irb(main):001:0> user = User.new
```

e depois disse informa uma mensagem de 'Não foi possível localizar "utilizadores" de mesa'

```
irb(main):001:0> user = User.new
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table 'users'
    from /home/vagrant/local/ruby/gems/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:515:in `table_structure'
    from /home/vagrant/local/ruby/gems/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:390:in `columns'
    from /home/vagrant/local/ruby/gems/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:93:in `block in prepare_default_proc'
    from /home/vagrant/local/ruby/gems/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:44:in `yield'
    from /home/vagrant/local/ruby/gems/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:44:in `columns'
    from /home/vagrant/local/ruby/gems/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:214:in `columns'
    from /home/vagrant/local/ruby/gems/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:223:in `columns_hash'
    from /home/vagrant/local/ruby/gems/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:180:in `subclass_from_attributes?'
    from /home/vagrant/local/ruby/gems/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:23:in `new'
    from (irb):1
    from /home/vagrant/local/ruby/gems/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
    from /home/vagrant/local/ruby/gems/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /home/vagrant/local/ruby/gems/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:69:in `console'
    from /home/vagrant/local/ruby/gems/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
    from /home/vagrant/local/ruby/gems/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/vagrant/local/ruby/gems/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    from /home/vagrant/local/ruby/gems/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
    from /home/vagrant/local/ruby/gems/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/vagrant/local/ruby/gems/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    from /vagrant/colchonet/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/vagrant/local/ruby/gems/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
    from /home/vagrant/local/ruby/gems/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `block in load'
    from /home/vagrant/local/ruby/gems/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/vagrant/local/ruby/gems/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'irb(main):002:0>
```

Comment: Agora foi. Faltou o rake db:migrate
valeu

Comment: @Andrey Deu certo. Coloca como resposta para eu dar como certo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mensagem significa:

> Não foi possìvel encontrar a tabela "users."

É possível que você tenha criado o modelo mas esquecido de rodar a migração. Tente rodar:

> `rake db:migrate`